# Coalesce NULL to '-' in a Float data type column - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I have a calculated column `Total_Count` which is derived from couple of `float` data type columns with results like `0, 101, NULL` (in `Total_Count` column).

Instead of showing `NULL` I want to show `- (hyphen character)` in the `Total_Count` column.

If I use `COALESCE(Total_Count, '-')` then I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 62
>
> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in select

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(Total_Count AS VARCHAR), '-')
```